# Marking a Record as Read AND Opening Up a New Page to Display the Data

Tags: c#

I have a DataGrid that I use to display an "inbox" of information. I would like the have the person click on a link which would mark the record as read and have the information display in a new window. I am relatively new to C#. What would be a good approach to accomplishing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the onclick event of the datagrid, retrieve the row selected, Grab the DataBoundItem and cast it back to your datatype. Update the Read property, and then pass that instance to a new form for display.